# Car tyre & surface recording without engine sound.

Tags: car, tyre, surfaces, engine, recording

Car tyre & surfaces recording without engine sound.
I want to record different surfaces in average speed (Gravel, tarmac, mud, water, sand,  etc...).
Any ideas ?

Comment: i did a bit of this recently:
http://www.musicofsound.co.nz/blog/gravel-tyres-recording

Answer (score 11):

A few suggestions:

- find a downhill slope, so you can get up to speed, kill the motor and record steady state onboard sounds
- up & stops are ok, just get up to speed & turn off the motor
- aways are trickier, again a steep downhill slope may be the best way, even if you have to back up, get started a bit, kill the motor then slowly roll past recorders as gather speed from the slope

One thing to be aware of: some vehicles, mine included, have power steering & power assisted brakes. So when you turn off the motor your ability to steer and to stop is diminished. You will want a confident careful driver who is aware of this & does some tests before pulling up close to a recordist. Safety first!

Answer (score 3):

My immediate answer would be to try and get access to an electric car - no engine noise and you can run them at fair speeds these days.

Comment: Well, not unless you get an audi e-tron! :P

http://ad-spoonz.blogspot.com/2012/05/cubenx-audis-e-sound.html

Comment: Tesla Roadster is quite a common choice for this kind of recording - http://www.tracktimeaudio.com/?p=401 

Comment: Because it's a very lightweight carbon body car, the Tesla roadster has a lot of wind, road and body noise, and even the engine isn't all that silent.
If you can, try to find a current electric non-sportscar with a normal weight and metal bodywork.